# How to find which Tmux session a process belongs to?

Tags: unix, process, tmux

Case in point is editing a configuration file in vim and inadvertently leaving it open. Then you go about your business, switch around in different Tmux sessions, eventually edit the same file from another session and vim will tell you a .swp file already exists.

Now, how do you find which Tmux session the other vim holding the file open is in? Findw seems to only search through active session windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`lsof /path/to/.file.swp` will show the process ID of the offending vim process. If you want to write a script, use `pid=$(lsof -Fp "$swp_file"); pid=${pid#p}` to get just the process ID.

Then `ps 12345` where 12345 is the process ID will show some information about the process, in particular what tty it's running on (`ps -o tty= -p $pid` in a script). The tty uniquely identifies a tmux window (assuming the process is running inside tmux), but I don't know how to go from the tty name to the tmux session.

What would give you the tmux session is the value of the `TMUX` environment variable in the vim process. The session number is the last number, after the last comma.

Most unices have a way to find out the environment of a process, but the way differs between unix variants. On Linux, you can use `</proc/$pid/environ grep -z '^TMUX='` to show the value of `$TMUX` in process `$pid`, so you can extract the session number as `$(</proc/$pid/environ grep -z '^TMUX=' | sed 's/.*,//')`.

Comment: yes indeed, this basically works, at least for scenario when original vi process isn't sudoed. /proc/$pid/environ was new to me, good thinking on that. getting the session value as a number is good enough since the session id letters >9 simply increase alphabetically.

Comment: when using sudo to launch the hypothetical vi process to find session by, it looks like it needs to have sudo -E for the TMUX variable to travel into it's environ.

Comment: @lkraav: Best: use `sudoedit` instead of `sudo vim`. Also useful to know for other cases: either use `sudo -E` or put `Defaults !env_reset` in `/etc/sudoers`. In a pinch: find out the parent process of `vim`, which is likely to be a shell running in the same tmux window, and get its `TMUX` variable.

Comment: Accessing `/proc/pid/environ` did not work for me using sudo, but with `cat` it works

Answer (score 7):

This shell snippet works pretty well for me (you'll need the pstree utility as well):

```
for s in `tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}'` ; do
  echo -e "\ntmux session name: $s\n--------------------"
  for p in `tmux list-panes -s -F '#{pane_pid}' -t "$s"` ; do
    pstree -p -a -A $p
  done
done
```

For two tmux sessions with two vim's each, I get this output:

```
tmux session name: 0
--------------------
zsh,3444
  `-vim,3467 file_1
zsh,3474
  `-vim,3495 file_2

tmux session name: 1
--------------------
zsh,3526
  `-vim,3547 file_3
zsh,3554
  `-vim,3576 file_4
```

Comment: great, thanks! also, adding `-h` in `pstree` call will highlight the current pane, FWIW; or, passing `-P $PID` instead should highlight some $PID you might be searching. But you don't really need this, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating using the response from Tor, a small bash snippet to get the session, window and pane where a particular PID is running:

```
export PID=1161102; for s in `tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}'` ; do
  for p in `tmux list-panes -s -F '#{pane_pid}' -t "$s"` ; do
    pstree -h -p -a -A $p | grep "[,]$PID" && tmux list-panes -s -t "$s" -f "#{==:#{pane_pid},$p}" -F '#{session_name}: #{window_index}.#{pane_index}'
  done
done
```

Example output:

```
  `-skydive,1161102 analyzer -c skydive.yml
SESSIONNAME: 2.3
```